# Should "rather" be used in this context?

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Translating from german, the word "rather" (as replacement for "ziemlich") sounds kind of wrong to me, but I would like to check with an example:

"Rather innovative", shouldn't it be "Quite innovative" or "Fairly innovative" instead?

The context here is a basic rating (in english), with 4 values (imagine a dropdown):

- "Not innovative"
- "Somewhat innovative"
- "(Rather) innovative"
- "Very innovative"

"The project is rather innovative"

The word "rather" is also used in other 4-tier choices like that. It has been translated by a colleague and just sounded wrong to me, but I wanted to double check since neither of us is a native english speaker. Translation software offers "rather" as a possibility.

What is the most naturally sounding choice here? Is "rather" the right word, or would another word be a better fit?

Comment: Look at FF's '...In certain contexts, these kind of qualifiers can all have their own special nuances, but it would be a mistake to infer any consistent rule regarding which to use when. Nor is there any consistent hierarchy of "intensity" for rather, quite, pretty, very, etc.'. Though I think you're right here. 'Rather' connotes a slightly patronising enthusiasm here; I'd go with 'quite' in its place too. Both are very variable in 'force'. 'Somewhat' is less than 40%. 'Quite' is even less precise, but sounds more encouraging. 'Pretty' sounds even more encouraging, but far less formal.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It is an interesting question and your comments add significantly to my answer, giving more body to the hierarchical idea that is difficult to pursue within authoritative sources. Many Thanks. {I see that it looks as if my answer sat unposted for a while. Hey ho!}

Answer (score 1):

On this site ([personlongman](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00336.html)) you will find ***quite*** a good clarification:

> In general, ***rather*** has less force than quite. ***Rather*** means "****somewhat***, to a certain degree."* ***Quite***, in contrast, can mean *"to a significant degree. "* When someone is ***rather sad***, the degree of sadness is less than if the person is ***quite sad***.

So in the classification of your values, I would use ***quite innovative***, since ***rather*** means what is already mentioned in nr 2 (Somewhat innovative).

Comment: Do you consider "quite **innovative**"  (weak quite), "quite innovative" (equal stress), and "**quite** innovative" (strong quite) as having the same strength?

Answer (score 1):

In these circumstances I suggest the meaning is:

> *rather* = *very*; *to a large degree*
>
> "Actually, I did rather well in my exams."
>
> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rather)

> *rather* = *in some degree* : *Somewhat*
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rather)

As such, the meaning is close to (and probably between) *somewhat* (= to a limited extent) and *very* (= to a large extent).

In some circumstances it may even mean *slightly* (= to a small extent). "You ate too much ice cream? That was rather silly of you wasn't it?"

I can think of no circumstance where *rather* means *not* or *completely*.

Consequently it is easy to suggest that *rather* sits in a rough hierarchy of meaning that ranges through *not* - *slightly* - *somewhat* - *rather* - *very* - *thoroughly* - *completely*. Others may place it rather (sic) differently in the range but it does not sit at the top or bottom of the range.

Comment: The definitions you give are pretty distinct polysemes. I'd say that 'rather innovative' is ambiguous between the two, not halfway between the two.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Agreed, although I have a little difficulty with *ambiguous* applied to a trio of meanings.

Comment: I see only two (though both ill-defined, indefinite).. 'Somewhat' covers 'to a small degree' as well as 'up to 40%'.

Comment: I referred to the placing of a meaning of *rather* between two other meanings. That is the trio I mean. But then, as you may know, there are three sorts of mathematicians: those who can count, and those who can't. :)